# Reading data from a log file as a separate application is writing to it

Tags: c++, perl, macos, file-io, logging

I would like to monitor a log file that is being written to by an application. I want to process the file line by line as, or shortly after, it is written. I have not found a way of detecting that a file has been extended after reaching eof.

The code needs to work on Mac and PC, and can be in any language, though I am most familiar with C++ and Perl.

Does anybody have a suggestion for the best way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Perl, the [File::Tail](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Tail/) module does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 3):

A generic enough answer:

Most languages, on EOF, return that no data were read. You can re-try reading after an interval, and if the file has grown since, this time the operating system will return data.

Answer (score 3):

The essense of `tail -f` is the following loop:

```
open IN, $file;
while(1) {
  my $line = <IN>;
  if($line) {
    #process line...
  } else {
    sleep(1);
    seek(IN,0,1);
  }
}
close IN;
```

The [seek](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/perl-5.10.0/pod/perlfunc.pod#seek) call is to clear the EOF flag.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use read the standard io from tail -f

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought outputting the actions via tee, and thence tail'ing (or using the loop [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62832#63446)) the file created by tee some use.