# how to track a file in my machine in c++

Tags: c++, windows

Is there a way by which i can track a file programmatic-ally on my machine i.e whether it is copied somewhere else or modified.

Tracking whether it is copied somewhere else is very important. File name might also have been changed

Comment: No. I really don't know what else to say.

Comment: Checking if a file is modified is quite easy, just check it's date of last modification.  Whether it's been copied, that sounds a bit difficult to near impossible.  What's the etc.?

Comment: ya i figured out the modified part.. by etc i mean if copied name might be changed also so I cant search the machine for same name

Comment: See [this][1] thread for ways to monitor files/folders.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931093/how-do-i-make-my-program-watch-for-file-modification-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on Windows, look into the [Journal API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/aa363798.aspx).