# How Windows Media Player tracks file movements?

Tags: .net, windows, filesystems

How does Windows Media Player media library track the movements of a file across the disk ?

I can add a file in WMP, cut / paste it elsewhere (on the same disk), and it'll know where it is.

Does it use windows shortcuts ? Or is there a cleaner solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try taking a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931093/how-do-i-make-my-program-watch-for-file-modification-in-c

Comment: Thanks, i wanted to track files while the application is closed. But it'll help nevertheless !