# Is there a way to monitor file changes using Boost library?

Tags: c++, boost

Similar to inotify in c++, is there any way in Boost library to monitor file changes?
My C++ program doesn't have inotify.h in the sys folder. I am searching for an alternative program with similar function in Boost.

Comment: Note: inotify is not something C++ specific, but a [linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) feature.

Comment: No, boost doesn't offer file monitoring. Are you looking for a cross-platform solution? or just Linux?

Comment: No, as mentioned in above comments. But take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931093/how-do-i-make-my-program-watch-for-file-modification-in-c for further information.