# Waiting signal to continue C++

Tags: c++, signals, wait

I have to start my programme every morning and this one has to wait few files during the day. I would like to know if anyone has a clean idea for my programme to wait during each treatment of file. It has to be cross-platform in C++.

For the moment I have just a while which check if the directory is empty or not.

Comment: What do you mean? Like an actual sleep? If so, why?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you need your program to do. Your question doesn't make much sense the way it's currently described.

Comment: `Qt` has a cross platform file / folder modification watcher: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html

Comment: Seems like a duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931093/how-do-i-make-my-program-watch-for-file-modification-in-c

Comment: There is also this: https://github.com/simongeilfus/Watchdog