# SQLite Data Change Notification Callbacks in Python or Bash or CLI

Tags: python, bash, sqlite, command-line-interface

SQLite has [Data Change Notification Callbacks](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/update_hook.html) available in the C API. Can these callbacks be used from the SQLite CLI, or from Bash or from Python?

If so, how?

Comment: from Go lang ... https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-sqlite/go1/sqlite3#Conn.UpdateFunc

Comment: On PyPI, apsw has bindings: http://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/connection.html#apsw.Connection.setupdatehook

Comment: related: [Launch a Python Script from a sqlite3 Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33021255/4279)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Can these callbacks be used from the SQLite CLI...

Reading through the SQLite source code, it doesn't look like that function is used anywhere in the CLI source code, so I doubt you can do it via the CLI.

> ...or from Bash...

Not sure what you mean by that.

> ...or from Python?

It's not exposed via the standard [`sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) module, but you can use it with the [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) module.

> If so, how?

Here's a quick n' dirty example of using it via `ctypes`...

```
from ctypes import *

# Define some symbols
SQLITE_DELETE =  9
SQLITE_INSERT = 18
SQLITE_UPDATE = 23

# Define our callback function
#
# 'user_data' will be the third param passed to sqlite3_update_hook
# 'operation' will be one of: SQLITE_DELETE, SQLITE_INSERT, or SQLITE_UPDATE
# 'db name' will be the name of the affected database
# 'table_name' will be the name of the affected table
# 'row_id' will be the ID of the affected row
def callback(user_data, operation, db_name, table_name, row_id):
    if operation == SQLITE_DELETE:
        optext = 'Deleted row'
    elif operation == SQLITE_INSERT:
        optext = 'Inserted row'
    elif operation == SQLITE_UPDATE:
        optext = 'Updated row'
    else:
        optext = 'Unknown operation on row'
    s = '%s %ld of table "%s" in database "%s"' % (optext, row_id, table_name, db_name)
    print(s)

# Translate into a ctypes callback
c_callback = CFUNCTYPE(c_void_p, c_void_p, c_int, c_char_p, c_char_p, c_int64)(callback)

# Load sqlite3
dll = CDLL('libsqlite3.so')

# Holds a pointer to the database connection
db = c_void_p()

# Open a connection to 'test.db'
dll.sqlite3_open('test.db', byref(db))

# Register callback
dll.sqlite3_update_hook(db, c_callback, None)

# Create a variable to hold error messages
err = c_char_p()

# Now execute some SQL
dll.sqlite3_exec(db, b'create table foo (id int, name varchar(255))', None, None, byref(err))
if err:
    print(err.value)
dll.sqlite3_exec(db, b'insert into foo values (1, "Bob")', None, None, byref(err))
if err:
    print(err.value)
```

...which prints out...

```
Inserted row 1 of table "foo" in database "main"
```

...on the first run and...

```
table foo already exists
Inserted row 2 of table "foo" in database "main"
```

...on the second run.

Comment: "Not sure what you mean by that." I mean, from a Bash script; e.g. one that wraps the SQLite CLI, or that intercepts arguments/options passed to the `sqlite3` command.

Comment: N.B. Your line `dll = CDLL('libsqlite3.so')` may need on some platforms to be changed to `dll = CDLL('libsqlite3.0.dylib')`

Comment: @sampablokuper Regarding the bash script comment: the SQLite CLI doesn't use the `sqlite3_update_hook()` function anywhere in its code, so I don't see how you could do it using a bash script which only wraps/intercepts the `sqlite3` command.

Comment: @sampablokuper Regarding `dll = CDLL('libsqlite3.0.dylib')`: I guess that's the OSX way, and you'd need to use something like `dll = CDLL('sqlite3.dll')` on Windows.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the database is updated in a different process.

Comment: @vy32 That's a limitation of sqlite. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/677028).