# Why trigger in SQlite3 is not waiting for commit?

Tags: python, sqlite, triggers

I have problem with calling python function after sqlite3 insert.

I found example there, but is not passing my conditions. Link: [Launch a Python Script from a sqlite3 Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33021255/9403794)

My code is similar, but inside function I want to select all inserted values.

```
import sqlite3

def hello():
    print ("Hello is executing")
    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect('test1.db')
        sql = "SELECT x FROM t WHERE 1==1"
        cur = con.cursor()
        for row in  cur.execute(sql):
            print(row)
    except Exception as e:
        print('ttt')
        print(e)

con = sqlite3.connect('test1.db')
con.create_function("hello",0, hello)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t(x)")
cur.execute("CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS tt  AFTER INSERT ON t BEGIN SELECT hello(); END;")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO t VALUES(2)")
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Problem is that when I first time execute a script I do not see inserted value in hello() function. Program is printing only:

```
Hello is executing
```

It is looking like trigger is executing a job before commit instruction.

Is that bug on SQlite3 or is other way to see inserted value in python function?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

The bug is not in SQLite3; it is in the program.  "*trigger is executing a job before commit instruction*" is true. The proximate cause is because a new connection to the database is created in the function, the trigger executes before the commit, therefore the SELECT in the function does not "know" the new row. Do not create a new connection in the function.

Comment: @ DinoCoderSaurus Thank you for explanation. I found other solution, but more dangerous. I added commit in function before cur.execute(). But your idea is much better.

Comment: If hello() is in the same file with connection to sqlite all is working. But if I move hello to other file I have error : name 'con' is not defined. How to pass connection to db if function is in other file?

Comment: That istechnically  a different question, and I don't know the answer.