# Sqlite update hook with external database

Tags: python, sqlite

Basically i'm developing an application in python where it listens to external sqlite database changes, so far i implemented update_hook()(from this example: [SQLite Data Change Notification Callbacks in Python or Bash or CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872700/sqlite-data-change-notification-callbacks-in-python-or-bash-or-cli/16920926#16920926)) it worked well when i launch SQL statements in the same process however when i use external database that has now relation with my process it doesn't work.
My question is how do i listen to database changes from an external process(A) that has no relation with process(B).

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has no mechanism by which another process can be notified.

You have to implement some communication mechanism outside of SQLite.

Comment: Like sockets for example ?