# How do I watch a folder for changes and when changes are done using Python?

Tags: python, monitoring, pywin32, watch

i need to watch a folder for incoming files. i did that with the following help:
[How do I watch a file for changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python)
the problem is that the files that are being moved are pretty big (10gb)
and i want to be notified when all files are done moving.
i tried comparing the size of the folder every 20 seconds but the file shows its correct size even tough windows shows that it is still moving.
i am using windows with python

> i found a solution using open and waiting for an io exception.
>   if the file is still being moved i get errno 13.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python

Comment: like i wrote i already seen it

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at this link:

http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

There you can see the comparison of the method you are speaking about (simple polling) with two other windows-specific techniques which, in my opinion, offers a really better solution to your problem!

Otherwise, if you are using linux, there's iNotify and the relative Python wrapper:

> Pyinotify is a pure Python module used
>   for monitoring filesystems events on
>   Linux platforms through  inotify
>
> Here: http://trac.dbzteam.org/pyinotify

Comment: his last sentence states that his OS is Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the process of importing the files, I would put a lock file when starting to copy files in, and remove it when you are done. by lock file I mean a tmp empty file, which is just there to indicate that you are coping a file. then your py script can check for the existence of the lock files.

Comment: sorry, i have no control, but a nice idea

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use `os.stat()` to monitor the mtime of the file. However be aware that under various network conditions, the copy may stall momentarily and so the mtime is not updated for a few seconds, so you need to make allowance for this.

Another option is to try opening the file with exclusive read/write which should fail under windows if the file is still opened by the other process

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable method would be to write your own program to move the files.

Answer (score 0):

try checking for the last-modified time change instead of the filesize during your poll.