# determining file changes in python

Tags: python, django

I have a text file being written by another process on a server which I want to watch for changes. Each time a change occurs I'd like to read the new data and send it to client .
Any suggestions will be valuable . Using Django,Python

Tazim.

Comment: duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a recent Linux you should look into this:

http://trac.dbzteam.org/pyinotify

[How do I watch a file for changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python)
goes into details for win32

Answer (score 0):

On Linux a convenient interface for file modification monitoring is [Gamin the File Alteration Monitor](http://people.gnome.org/~veillard/gamin/). Python bindings are provided and they are really easy to use, though they could be documented better (especially the 'magic numbers' returned).