# How to refresh gimp project when other program modifies opened .xcf?

Tags: linux, plugins, gimp

Lets say I have .xcf opened in gimp and then some other program (maybe gimp too) changes same .xcf file. How to programmatically (by linux signal, gimp plugin) autorefresh (automatically closing and opening project might do) gimp when this happens.

Comment: I was looking through options/properties/*rc files. Plugin would do, but it's not as easy as it sounds, because one can only operate on image buffer - am I right?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there is no plug in for gimp that allows you to do so.

But you could create one. You just need to know the Python basics and maybe also read this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622796/a-way-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-file-system-from-python-on-linux). After that you'll easily be able to solve your probleme.

Comment: Hope I could help you even if this was a little bit late :D

Comment: Nope that's not what I want. I meant programmatically, without pressing any button, it should happen automatically when edited file (.xcf) is being changed (not by gimp).

Comment: How about this? I searched through the whole plugin list of gimp: http://registry.gimp.org/ but there was no plugin like you need it.