# How to watch a directory for changes?

Tags: python, filesystemwatcher

Could not find anything in python core to do this. Can anyone recommend a library or "battery" to do this? Ideally I would like this to be portable but it's OK if it is available only for Unix (my server).

Comment: Some more answers here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python

Answer (score 13):

On Linux, you could be interested in pyinotify

1. https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify

Other related libraries:

1. http://people.gnome.org/~veillard/gamin/python.html
2. Python FAM interface: http://python-fam.sourceforge.net/
3. http://gorakhargosh.github.com/watchdog/

Comment: [inotify_simple](https://github.com/chrisjbillington/inotify_simple) is pretty good and much simple than pyintoify in my opinion

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's something portable for this kind of requirement.
That's too close to the OS IMO.
Otherwise for Linux, there's [pynotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify).
pyinotify is a binding for Linux inotify kernel filesystem notification subsystem.
Works quite well.

Comment: I too had the same understanding that this can't be portable. Luckily my hosting is in Linux and so pynotify is quite suffice. Some developers still use win but i actually don't expect them to use or work on this module.

Answer (score 4):

I was just looking for a python package that watches file modifications. Just stumbled upon **pywatch** and it might just be what you're looking for. It's very simple, but does what I need (fixing pyScss' lack of a watcher).

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywatch