# How to run infinite while loop on list

Tags: python, list, loops

I’m trying run this code on my Ubuntu machine so it will take any new .txt file from the out folder to the in folder, but I'm probably doing something wrong because it does not work.

```
import shutil
import os

os.chdir("/test/out")
srcdir = os.listdir("/test/out")
dstdir = "/test/in"
srcdir = True

def filemv():
    for file in srcdir:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            shutil.move(file, dstdir)
            print(file)
while srcdir is True:
    filemv()
```

Comment: This will max the CPU and probably cause the system to freeze. You should re-think your idea.

Comment: `for file in srcdir` fails, because it is True and you can't loop over that.

Comment: Apart from the errors in your code already pointed out: What's your definition of "working"? What's the expected result, and what result do you actually get?

Comment: Also, you have declare `srcdir` two times... It's a boolean and not the result of `os.listdir()` as you might expected.

Comment: hi Lukas, i want this little script to listen on the srcdir for new *.txt file. once new file got into the the folder it will immediately move to dstdir. thanks guy

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you call `os.listdir()` just once. If you don't call it again, you won't notice any new files.

Also, running a busy loop for this sort of thing is probably a bad idea. Take a look at [How to watch a directory for changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708511/how-to-watch-a-directory-for-changes-in-python) and links therein.