# Can I detect the start of a download with selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, download

I'm using Python & Selenium to download a large number of files (yes, I do need to). Currently, to make sure a file downloads, I have a simple time.sleep() statement, but I'd like to both improve efficiency and make guarantees that I've downloaded each file.

Unfortunately, I don't have a list of file paths such that I can use some other suggested solutions for general file downloads.

What I'm dealing with is the following on-click javascript:

```
onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView1','OpenFile$0')
```

So I'd like to be able to detect that one file has begun downloading before clicking on the next one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you should probably implement in the other way round by checking the file has downloaded completely (by using **os.path.exists()** before clicking the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar approach to what @Anzel suggested.

Use [`watchdog`](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/) to watch the *Browser Downloads* directory. Once there is a new file appearing, you know that a download has started. See also:

- [How to watch a directory for changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708511/how-to-watch-a-directory-for-changes-in-python)
- [Monitoring contents of files/directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597903/monitoring-files-directories-with-python)

Comment: Would this work if I'm downloading multiple files at the same time? My current code has multiple browsers open at the same time, downloading files to the same directory.

Comment: @pshee depends. If you know the filename that should appear - than yes. Or, if you can create a separate sub-directory in the main Downloads directory and watch them separately - then also yes.