# python selenium, find out when a download has completed?

Tags: python, selenium

I've used selenium to initiate a download. After the download is complete, certain actions need to be taken, is there any simple method to find out when a download has complete? (I am using the FireFox driver)

Comment: with chrome, to monitor the download progress, just parse the `chrome://downloads` page. see also [How best to test file download links using Selenium](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/27342/57619)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no built-in to selenium way to wait for the download to be completed.

---

The general idea here would be to *wait until a file would appear in your "Downloads" directory*.

This might either be achieved by looping over and over again checking for file existence:

- [Check and wait until a file exists to read it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746750/check-and-wait-until-a-file-exists-to-read-it)

Or, by using things like `watchdog` to monitor a directory:

- [How to watch a directory for changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708511/how-to-watch-a-directory-for-changes-in-python)
- [Monitoring contents of files/directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597903/monitoring-files-directories-with-python)

Answer (score 65):

I came across this problem recently. I was downloading multiple files at once and had to build in a way to timeout if the downloads failed.

The code checks the filenames in some download directory every second and exits once they are complete or if it takes longer than 20 seconds to finish. The returned download time was used to check if the downloads were successful or if it timed out.

```
import time
import os

def download_wait(path_to_downloads):
    seconds = 0
    dl_wait = True
    while dl_wait and seconds < 20:
        time.sleep(1)
        dl_wait = False
        for fname in os.listdir(path_to_downloads):
            if fname.endswith('.crdownload'):
                dl_wait = True
        seconds += 1
    return seconds
```

I believe that this only works with chrome files as they end with the .crdownload extension. There may be a similar way to check in other browsers.

Edit: I recently changed the way that I use this function for times that `.crdownload` does not appear as the extension. Essentially this just waits for the correct number of files as well.

```
def download_wait(directory, timeout, nfiles=None):
    """
    Wait for downloads to finish with a specified timeout.

    Args
    ----
    directory : str
        The path to the folder where the files will be downloaded.
    timeout : int
        How many seconds to wait until timing out.
    nfiles : int, defaults to None
        If provided, also wait for the expected number of files.

    """
    seconds = 0
    dl_wait = True
    while dl_wait and seconds < timeout:
        time.sleep(1)
        dl_wait = False
        files = os.listdir(directory)
        if nfiles and len(files) != nfiles:
            dl_wait = True

        for fname in files:
            if fname.endswith('.crdownload'):
                dl_wait = True

        seconds += 1
    return seconds
```

Comment: Way better than the accepted answer (that actually provides no solution at all).

Comment: This simply solved my problems! Agreed, much better than accepted!

Comment: Doesn't work anymore. Chrome no longer uses *.crdownload temporary files. It now uses some crazy temporary names for 'safety reasons'.

Answer (score 15):

```
import os
import time

def latest_download_file():
      path = r'Downloads folder file path'
      os.chdir(path)
      files = sorted(os.listdir(os.getcwd()), key=os.path.getmtime)
      newest = files[-1]

      return newest

fileends = "crdownload"
while "crdownload" == fileends:
    time.sleep(1)
    newest_file = latest_download_file()
    if "crdownload" in newest_file:
        fileends = "crdownload"
    else:
        fileends = "none"
```

This is a combination of a few solutions. I didn't like that I had to scan the entire downloads folder for a file ending in "crdownload". This code implements a function that pulls the newest file in downloads folder. Then it simply checks if that file is still being downloaded. Used it for a Selenium tool I am building worked very well.

Comment: I thinked the same some time ago, is nice.

Answer (score 8):

I know its too late for the answer, though would like to share a hack for future readers.

You can create a thread say *thread1* from main thread and initiate your download here.
Now, create some another thread, say *thread2* and in there ,let it wait till *thread1* completes using join() method.Now here,you can continue your flow of execution after download completes.

Still make sure you dont initiate your download using selenium, instead extract the link using selenium and use requests module to download.

[Download using requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16696317/8520798)

For eg:

```
def downloadit():
     #download code here    

def after_dwn():
     dwn_thread.join()           #waits till thread1 has completed executing
     #next chunk of code after download, goes here

dwn_thread = threading.Thread(target=downloadit)
dwn_thread.start()

metadata_thread = threading.Thread(target=after_dwn)
metadata_thread.start()
```

Comment: If you don't need authentication fine. But most cases we need....

Answer (score 6):

As answered before, there is no native way to check if download is finished. So here is a helper function that does the job for Firefox and Chrome. One trick is to clear the temp download folder before start a new download. Also, use native pathlib for cross-platform usage.

```
from pathlib import Path

def is_download_finished(temp_folder):
    firefox_temp_file = sorted(Path(temp_folder).glob('*.part'))
    chrome_temp_file = sorted(Path(temp_folder).glob('*.crdownload'))
    downloaded_files = sorted(Path(temp_folder).glob('*.*'))
    if (len(firefox_temp_file) == 0) and \
       (len(chrome_temp_file) == 0) and \
       (len(downloaded_files) >= 1):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Good one, didn't think about it in this way. Works great

Answer (score 3):

Check for "Unconfirmed" key word in file name in download directory:

```
# wait for download complete
wait = True
while(wait==True):
    for fname in os.listdir('\path\to\download directory'):
        if ('Unconfirmed') in fname:
            print('downloading files ...')
            time.sleep(10)
        else:
            wait=False
print('finished downloading all files ...')
```

As soon as the the filed download is completed it exits the while loop.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

- poll for the *existence* of the file
- poll for *non-zero filesize* of that file

**Observed Behaviour**

I noticed that there can be a lag between a downloaded file appearing in the filesystem and the contents of that file being fully written, especially noticeable with large files.

I did some experimenting, using `stat_result` from `os.stat()` on Linux, and found the following,

- when a file is **first opened** for writing

  - `st_size == 0`
  - `st_atime == st_mtime == st_ctime`
- while data is **being written** to the file

  - `st_size == 0`
  - `st_atime == st_mtime == st_ctime`
- once the writing is complete and the **file is closed**

  - `st_size > 0`
  - `st_atime < st_mtime == st_ctime`

**Implementation**

- Poll for a file using glob with a configurable timeout

  - This is useful when you don't know *exactly* what the name of the downloaded file will be
- Poll for the filesize of a specific file to be above a threshold

```py
import glob
import polling2
import os

def poll_for_file_glob(file_glob: str, step: int=1, timeout: int=20):
    try:
        polling2.poll(lambda: len(glob.glob(file_glob)), step=step, timeout=timeout)
    except polling2.TimeoutException:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Unable to find file matching glob '{file_glob}'")
    return glob.glob(file_glob)[0]

def poll_for_file_size(file_path: str, size_threshold: int=0, step: int=1, timeout: int=20):
    try:
        polling2.poll(lambda: os.stat(file_path).st_size > size_threshold, step=step, timeout=timeout)
    except polling2.TimeoutException:
        file_size = os.stat(file_path).st_size
        raise RuntimeError(f"File '{file_path}' has size {file_size}, which is not larger than threshold {size_threshold}")
    return os.stat(file_path).st_size
```

You might use these functions like this,

```py
try:
  file_glob = "file_*.csv"
  file_path = poll_for_file_glob(file_glob=file_glob)
  file_size = poll_for_file_size(file_path=file_path)
except:
  print(f"Problem polling for file matching '{file_glob}'")
else:
  print(f"File '{file_path}' ({file_size}B) is ready")
```

Comment: Stumbled on this answer as I am having the same issues, noticing an incosistent delay sometimes when the code seems to run faster than the system can write the file or something. Will try and implement this in my code and report back. The other answers do not seem to deal with this problem

Answer (score 2):

```
x1=0
while x1==0:
    count=0
    li = os.listdir("directorypath")
    for x1 in li:
        if x1.endswith(".crdownload"):
             count = count+1        
    if count==0:
        x1=1
    else:
        x1=0
```

This works if you are trying to check if a set of files(more than one) have finished downloading.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me:

```
fileends = "crdownload"
while "crdownload" in fileends:
    sleep(1)
    for fname in os.listdir(some_path): 
        print(fname)
        if "crdownload" in fname:
            fileends = "crdownload"
        else:
            fileends = "None"
```

Answer (score 2):

If using Selenium and Chrome, you can write a custom wait condition such as:

```
class file_has_been_downloaded(object):
def __init__(self, dir, number):
    self.dir = dir
    self.number = number

def __call__(self, driver):
    print(count_files(dir), '->', self.number)
    return count_files(dir) > self.number
```

The function count_files just verifies that the file has been added to the folder

```
def count_files(direct):
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(direct):
    return len(list(f for f in files if f.startswith('MyPrefix') and (
            not f.endswith('.crdownload')) ))
```

Then to implement this in your code:

```
files = count_files(dir)
<< copy the file. Possibly use shutil >>
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(file_has_been_downloaded(dir, files))
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a better one though:

So redirect the function that starts the download. e.g. download_function= lambda: element.click()

than check number of files in directory and wait for a new file that doesnt have the download extension. After that rename it. (can be change to move the file instead of renaming it in the same directory)

```
def save_download(self, directory, download_function, new_name, timeout=30):
    """
    Download a file and rename it
    :param directory: download location that is set
    :param download_function: function to start download
    :param new_name: the name that the new download gets
    :param timeout: number of seconds to wait for download
    :return: path to downloaded file
    """
    self.logger.info("Downloading " + new_name)
    files_start = os.listdir(directory)
    download_function()
    wait = True
    i = 0
    while (wait or len(os.listdir(directory)) == len(files_start)) and i < timeout * 2:
        sleep(0.5)
        wait = False
        for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
            if file_name.endswith('.crdownload'):
                wait = True
    if i == timeout * 2:
        self.logger.warning("Documents not downloaded")
        raise TimeoutError("File not downloaded")
    else:
        self.logger.info("Downloading done")
        new_file = [name for name in os.listdir(directory) if name not in files_start][0]
        self.logger.info("New file found renaming " + new_file + " to " + new_name)
        while not os.access(directory + r"\\" + new_file, os.W_OK):
            sleep(0.5)
            self.logger.info("Waiting for write permission")
        os.rename(directory + "\\" + new_file, directory + "\\" + new_name)
        return directory + "\\" + new_file
```

Comment: I like the look of this. A little more complex than some other answers, but looks to be more robust. To adapt this for Firefox, look for files ending with .part instead of .crdownload
It might be worth using os.path.join instead of hardcoding "\\" to avoid the Windows vs Unix slash direction issue.

Comment: There's a bug in your code. You never increment the value of i. So if a download fails it will get stuck in the i < timeout * 2 condition.

Comment: I also found that every download would timeout if in a previous execution the browser crashed before finishing the download leaving a leftover .crdownload file in the downloads folder.

Answer (score 0):

With Chrome, files which have not finished downloading have the extension `.crdownload`. If you [set your download directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654358/how-to-control-the-download-of-files-with-selenium-python-bindings-in-chrome) properly, then you can wait until the file that you want no longer has this extension. In principle, this is not much different to waiting for file to exist (as [suggested by alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34338926/1571593)) - but at least you can monitor progress in this way.

Answer (score 0):

create a function that uses "requests" to get the file content and call that one, your program will not move forward unless the file is downloaded

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# Open the website
driver.get(website_url_)

x = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('download')
y = x.get_attribute("href")
fc = requests.get(y)
fname = x.text
with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(fc.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is VERY SIMPLE and worked for me (and works fot any extention)

```
import os, glob and time (not truly needed)

# count how many files you have in Downloads folder before download

user = os.getlogin()
downloads_folder = (r"C:/Users/" + user + "/Downloads/")
files_path = os.path.join(downloads_folder, '*')
files = sorted(glob.iglob(files_path), key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True)
files_before_download = files

print(f'files before download: {len(files)}')
finished = False

# ...
# code
# to
# download
# file
# ...

# just for extra safety
time.sleep(0.5)

# wait for the download to finish if there is +1 file in Downloads folder
while not finished:
    files = sorted(glob.iglob(files_path), key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True)
    print(len(files))
    if (len(files) == len(files_before_download)) or (len(files) == (len(files_before_download)+2)):
        print('not finished')
        finished = False
    else:
        print('finished')
        finished = True

last_downloaded_file = files[0]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

well, what if you check the size of the file until it has x size? There must be an average (Too bored to buid code, build it. Ideas helps too)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers:

```py
download_dir = '~/Downloads'


def check_downloaded_file(previous_cant_of_files_in_dir):
    new_file_was_created = False

    def _check_downloaded_file(driver):
        global download_dir
        nonlocal new_file_was_created

        if previous_cant_of_files_in_dir < download_folder_files_cant():
            new_file_was_created = True

        return (
            new_file_was_created
            and not last_downloaded_file().endswith('.crdownload')
        )

    return _check_downloaded_file


def download_folder_files_cant():
    global download_dir
    return len(glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f"{download_dir}/*")))


def do_and_wait_download(driver, todo, timeout=15):
    global download_dir

    previous_cant_of_files_in_dir = download_folder_files_cant()
    todo(driver)
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
        check_downloaded_file(previous_cant_of_files_in_dir)
    )


def click_element(driver, find_by, value):
    driver.find_element(find_by, value).click()


def click_link_and_wait_download(driver, find_by, value, timeout=15):
    return do_and_wait_download(
        driver,
        lambda d: click_element(d, find_by, value),
        timeout
    )
```

Use as:

```py
# If is just a click
click_link_and_wait_download(driver, By.ID, 'elementLink')

# If you extract the URL from element
url = driver.find_element(By.ID, "downloadButton").get_attribute('href')
do_and_wait_download(driver, lambda d: d.get(url))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know anything about the download filename (*.zip?), it is nicer to watch for future state than for crdownload. In my case I had to run this in a loop 700 times.

```
import glob
download_glob = r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\YourDownload*.zip'

def download_wait(dir_file_glob, expected_num_files, timeout=300):
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        if (len(glob.glob(dir_file_glob)) - expected_num_files) >= 0:
            return
        time.sleep(5)
        if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
            raise TimeoutError('No Download Found')

n_download_files = len(glob.glob(download_glob))
# activate download here
download_wait(download_glob, n_download_files+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me is:

```
def get_non_temp_len(download_dir):
    non_temp_files = [i for i in os.listdir(download_dir) if not (i.endswith('.tmp') or i.endswith('.crdownload'))]
    return len(non_temp_files)

download_dir = 'your/download/dir'
original_count = get_non_temp_len(download_dir) # get the file count at the start

# do your selenium stuff 

while original_count == get_non_temp_len(download_dir):
    time.sleep(.5) # wait for file count to change
    
driver.quit()
```

Credits do @LamerLink on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48263317/selenium-python-waiting-for-a-download-process-to-complete-using-chrome-web/62559494#62559494)