# Rename downloaded files selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using selenium to automatically download files in csv format from this page:

https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?tags=crime

This is the code I'm using:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", '/home/luis/Desktop/data/')
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
download_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div[2]/section[1]/div[2]/ul/li[14]/div/ul/li[1]/a')
download_button.click()
```

Here the download folder is set:

```
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", '/home/luis/Desktop/data/')
```

How can I select the name with which the file is saved?
Can be the name defined at the moment of the download?

I meant something like this:

```
For name in names:
    download_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div[2]/section[1]/div[2]/ul/li[14]/div/ul/li[{}]/a'.format(name))
    download_button.click()
    save_file_as(name)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*You don't have control over the download file naming through selenium*.

What you can do is to use a directory watcher/observer to detect when the file is downloaded and then rename it accordingly. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34338926/771848) containing more follow-up details.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os,glob

def get_last_filename_and_rename(save_folder, new_filename):
    files = glob.glob(save_folder + '/*')
    max_file = max(files, key=os.path.getctime)
    filename = max_file.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
    new_path = max_file.replace(filename, new_filename)
    os.rename(max_file, new_path)
    return new_path
```

Just a code sample. Find and rename the last downloaded file. * `new_filename` does not include an extension, it is inherited from the original file.