# Failed-Path Too Long error after downloading csv file using ChromeDriver and Chrome Browser launched by Selenium through cygwin in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I try to download csv file from the Chrome browser launched by selenium.

But

```
Failed- Path too long error
```

happens while downloading csv file.

path:

```
C:/s/d/b
```

I change path like below, but same error...

```
/cygdrive/c/s/d/a
\cygdrive\c\s\d\a
\\cygdrive\\c\\s\\d\\a
```

csv file

```
20181213171306.csv
```

chromedriver's path

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/HOGEHOGE/chromedriver_2.45.exe
```

Using cygwin, executing python scripts like this below.

```
python3 C:/s/d/a.py
```

I set the web driver option like this below.

```
DIR_DL="C:/s/d/b"
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory":DIR_DL,
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH,chrome_options=options)
driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': DIR_DL}}
command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

"失敗-パスが長すぎます" is Japanese. It means "Failed- Path too long error".

**[Environment]**
Windows 10 
CYGWIN_NT-10.0 2.11.2 
Python 3.6.4 
selenium 3.141.0
chrome driver 2.45
chrome browser 71

Comment: `C:/s/d/b` is real dir name? it is not too long, the problem maybe from your filename.

Comment: C:/s/d/b is real dir name. Down load csv file name cannot change, is it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459972/rename-downloaded-files-selenium

Comment: can you post full error message or the screenshot.

Comment: Hi @ewwink. Thank you for your reply. I post screen shot. Error logs does not show on the cygwin command line. I don't know how to debug. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the CSV Download path to cygwin's to dom's path, then I succeeded to download csv file.

CSV Download's path

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/CSV_DOWNLOAD_PATH
```

↓

```
C:/Users/CSV_DOWNLOAD_PATH
```

Many thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Try with double slash for the path name:

> C:\d\s\b

Try also setting the driver page downloads option on init of webdriver.

```
driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': "/path/to/download/dir"}}
command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried C:\s\d\a、C:\\s\\d\\a. But "Failed- Path too long error" occured.

Comment: I already wrote above scripts. I updated my question. Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0):

try set download directory using `add_argument`

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:/s/d/b")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: Same "Failed- Path too long error"  occured. This looks like browser launched by chromedriver does not understand path...

Comment: please open `chrome://settings/downloads` and see what the location path

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Failed-Path Too Long
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** failed to interact with the (recently) **downloaded** file.

---

As per the discussion [Wrong error - "Path Too Long" ... Error should be "File Already Open"](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137925) this issue is observed when the *WebDriver* instance i.e. the driver tries to use the downloaded file too soon.

Error Snapshot:

[image: Failed-Path Too Long]

---

### Solution

Induce some *wait* between the twp steps of:

- Downloading the csv file.
- Using the csv file for the next action.