# Python Selenium Headless download

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to download a file with selenium. I've searched everything.

At [How to control the download of files with Selenium Python bindings in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654358/how-to-control-the-download-of-files-with-selenium-python-bindings-in-chrome) some people told that it worked. 
But it didn't worked for me! Maybe I miss something? The only things differentlly is that my page autostarted download the csv file.

After studying the chrome codes I added:

```
        "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False
```

But still id didn't worked.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default_directory": "C:\\Users\\claudiu.ivanescu\\Downloads",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False
})
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')
options.add_argument('--headless')
```

Thank for support

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If anybody interested, after 2 days of search :). I manage to make it works!

I found the answer the bug tracking in this comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481#c86

The code I used is:

```
def enable_download_headless(browser,download_dir):
    browser.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
    params = {'cmd':'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_dir}}
    browser.execute("send_command", params)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--verbose')
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "download.default_directory": "C:\\tmp",
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": False
    })
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver_path = "C:\\Users\\tmp\\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options=options)
    enable_download_headless(driver, "C:/tmp")
    driver.get(url)
```

Maybe will be some use to others in the future...
Probably is a lot of useless things inside, but didn't have time yet to change :).

Comment: Hey, I tried to run your code, it did not produce any error but did not download the file either. After calling `enable_download_headless(driver, ".")`,  I did `btn_dl.click()` but it did nothing.

Comment: Selenium it's a difficult thing. It worked for me with the chromedriver from 2 years ago. You have to check the compatibilities between versions.

Comment: Voodoo magic, but a working voodoo magic.

Comment: Tried so many configurations of these arguments and couldn't get the download to work until I found your post. Thank you! This may have been what I needed:
`safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False`

Comment: Hai @Claudiu - after a long search this works for me and saves my time.

Comment: @Claudiu, I must extra login to SO to thank you for this. Thank you. Still work as of 01Nov2022.