# Web Scraping this site to get the output

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, midi

There is this site  https://colinhume.com/music.aspx which takes a certain input and converts it to an output file.

Let's say the input is :

```
X: 7
T:As Luck Will Have It
% Nottingham Music Database
S:John Lagden, via EF
M:6/8
K:D
E|"D"F3 "A7/c+"A2G|"Bm"FGF "A7"E3|"D"F2A d2c|"G"BcB "D"A3|"G"G2B "A7"A2G|\
"D"F2A d2f|
"G"efe "E7"dcB|"A7"ABA GFE|"D"F3 "A7/c+"A2G|"Bm"FGF "A7"E3|"D"F2A d2c|
"G"BcB "D"A3|"G"G2B "A7"A2G|"D"F2E "Bm"D2F|"Em"EFG "A7"F2E|"D"D3 -D2||
A|"D"d3 fed|"A"c2d e2A|"Bm"Bcd c2B|"F#m"A3 A2A|"G"B3 dcB|
"D"A2d f2a|"G"agf "E7"fed|"A7"e3 e2A|"D"d3 fed|"A"c2B A2A|
"Bm"B3 dcB|"F#m"A3 A2F|"G"G3 BAG|"D"F2A d2D|"Em"EFG "A7"F2E|"D"D3 -D2||
```

When you click on "Convert" button, there is an output page which has a "Play" button on the top. When you click the button, a midi file gets downloaded.

Now, is it possible for this whole process to be done by a python code automatically, which stores the midi file to my PC?

I need this code as a part of a project which should automatically convert that type of input to midi format. I have tried many offline codes, none of them seem to work properly.

So I hope I could do this with web scraping.

**Note: Input needs to be in certain format, so paste the above text as it is in the site.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to import [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) module to run this. Also you need to have the [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home) in your path. Maybe you already do since you mentioned web scraping.

EDIT: the code now doesn't show the GUI and downloads the file to the same folder of the py script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
download_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
params = {'cmd':'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_path}}
driver.execute("send_command", params)    

song = """X: 7
T:As Luck Will Have It
% Nottingham Music Database
S:John Lagden, via EF
M:6/8
K:D
E|"D"F3 "A7/c+"A2G|"Bm"FGF "A7"E3|"D"F2A d2c|"G"BcB "D"A3|"G"G2B "A7"A2G|\
"D"F2A d2f|
"G"efe "E7"dcB|"A7"ABA GFE|"D"F3 "A7/c+"A2G|"Bm"FGF "A7"E3|"D"F2A d2c|
"G"BcB "D"A3|"G"G2B "A7"A2G|"D"F2E "Bm"D2F|"Em"EFG "A7"F2E|"D"D3 -D2||
A|"D"d3 fed|"A"c2d e2A|"Bm"Bcd c2B|"F#m"A3 A2A|"G"B3 dcB|
"D"A2d f2a|"G"agf "E7"fed|"A7"e3 e2A|"D"d3 fed|"A"c2B A2A|
"Bm"B3 dcB|"F#m"A3 A2F|"G"G3 BAG|"D"F2A d2D|"Em"EFG "A7"F2E|"D"D3 -D2||"""

driver.get("https://colinhume.com/music.aspx")
input_element = driver.find_element_by_id("InBox")
input_element.send_keys(song)

button_element = driver.find_element_by_id("ConvBtn")
button_element.click()

button_elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("Button")
for button_element in button_elements:
    if button_element.text == "Play":
            driver.get(button_element.find_element_by_tag_name("a").get_attribute("href"))
            break
```

Comment: And also, is it possible to do this without actually making the chrome browser visible in the GUI?

Comment: Yes, you can use the headless behavior very easily, but the download needs also special treatment if you do. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830115/python-selenium-headless-download