# How to download a file on clicking a button element?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to follow the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52831544/275002). My code gives no error but it is not downloading file either. Below is my code:

```
def enable_download_headless(browser, download_dir):
    browser.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
    params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_dir}}
    browser.execute("send_command", params)
```

And this is the `__main__`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    CHROME_PATH = '/chromedriver'

    service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(CHROME_PATH)
    service.start()
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
    # options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {'download.prompt_for_download': 'true'})

    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "download.default_directory": ".",
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": False
    })

    options = options.to_capabilities()
    driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, options)
    driver.set_window_size(1400, 1000)
    enable_download_headless(driver, ".")
    driver.get("https://xx.xx.com/")
    login()
    # Go to the Dashboard
    url = 'https://xx.xx.com/d/aa-xx'
    driver.get(url)
    sleep(5)
    # btn_dl = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="panel-c"]/button[2]')
    # btn_dl = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#panel-controls > button.sc-dkAroR.crYcIE')
    btn_dl = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/button[2]")))

    if btn_dl:
        btn_dl.click() # It does not download
```

Comment: Is the clicking going through?

Comment: The click should download the file. I am not getting any error and script is exiting.

Comment: Is the default directory also set and you changed it.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I set it to the current by doing  `.`

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Even I set the absolute it does not download.