# How to set a custom directory to output selenium saved pdf files

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61013000) to download and save webpages as a pdf.

Although the method works, it is saving the output files in a different directory.

What could I add to the code to specify a custom output directory?

In addition to that, is there a way to change the output file name?

This is the code so far:

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
settings = {"recentDestinations": [{"id": "Save as PDF", "origin": "local", "account": ""}], "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF", "version": 2}
prefs = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(settings)}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide default directory in your preferences by adding `'savefile.default_directory'` with a path to your folder, like this:

```py
prefs = {
    'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(settings),
    'savefile.default_directory': '/path_to_folder/'
}
```

(Also, [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40656336/7746992) has an example of how the path should look for Windows)

As far, as saving the file with a custom name, I couldn't find an easy solution myself, but I used [this example from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61544031/7746992) when I was building something similar. I hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can specify your download directory.This is Java solution.

```
    downloadPath=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\tempDownloadedFiles";
```