# How can I rename the latest downloaded file?

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code, webbrowser-control

I'm using Selenium to automate a report but when I download it the last number changes as if it were a sequence for example: 0001849191, 0001849192 and so on. I can't make it keep following the order because if someone else generates the report it can skip a number and python doesn't understand that it followed the sequence and ends up not renaming, so I'd like to make it possible for it to check what the last downloaded file and after that he renames the .xlsx file. Here's the code I made to try more without success:

filepath = r'C:\Users\Luis.Serpa\Downloads'

filename = max([filepath +'\'+ f for f in os.listdir(filepath)], key=os.path.getmtime)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the glob and os module to get the latest file.First import os, glob modules i.e:

```
import os
import glob
```

Then you define path.My example gives path for any ones Download folder.

```
home = os.path.expanduser('~')
path = os.path.join(home, 'Downloads')
```

"*" is necessary.

```
path_a = path + "/*" # * means (match all), if specific format required then *.csv This will get all the files ending with .csv
list_of_files = glob.glob(path_a) 
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
```

This is name of new file

```
new_file = os.path.join(path, "b.kml")
print(latest_file)
#prints a.txt which was latest file i created
os.rename(latest_file, new_file)
```

the file name becomes b.kml

Answer (score 0):

First off, `'\'` is an invalid string, because `\` is used for escape sequences. `'\\'` would get you a string with a single backslash in it.

But more than that, it's best not to construct paths this way; you should use [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to create paths out of components:

```py
filename = max([os.path.join(filepath, f) for f in os.listdir(filepath)], key=os.path.getmtime)
```

This code works just fine to find the latest file on my OS, if I give a `filepath` to my own downloads folder.

For a more modern python3 approach that has better cross-platform path support, you can also use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Once you have the path of the file, you can rename it with [os.rename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename).

Comment: It worked he is renaming the file and playing in the directory folder, thank you very much.