Way to tell when a file is downloaded in Selenium?
I've got a bot that I'm writing in a Python Docker image to visit a webpage and download attachments from a post. The downloads aren't from a link, but are downloaded from clicking an element. The default download location is set to "tmp/downloads".
def get_attachments(driver):
    try:
        if driver.find_element(By.ID, "display-attachments-list"):
            attachments_list_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "display-attachments-list")))
            attachments_list_items = attachments_list_element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "li")
            if len(attachments_list_items) > 0:
                os.makedirs("/tmp/downloads", 511, True)
                for atch in attachments_list_items:
                    num_files = len(os.scandir("/tmp/downloads"))
                    scroll_to_element(driver, atch)
                    atch.click()
                    logger.info("Downloading attachment")
                    logger.info(atch.text)
                    for i in range(10):
                        if len(os.scandir("/tmp/downloads")) <= num_files:
                            time.sleep(1)
                        else:
                            break
                
            else:
                logger.info("No attachments found")
    except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, ElementClickInterceptedException) as e:
        logger.info("Post does not include attachments")
    scroll_to_top(driver)

Scandir does not return a list of objects like I thought it did. I could probably work with it but I know there must be a better way of doing this. Any thoughts?

most browsers will create a file while the file is downloading with a certain extension so that they can be resumed if download is interrupted.  (Chrome uses ".crdownload" methinks...) You could use a polling loop to check before you quit the driver to see if any of those files exist and wait until they are gone.  Btw, if you need to use os.makedirs, it's likely you have not set the download location properly.  The dir should exist and have proper permissions or the browser will use default location.

You might check the answer here for Chrome: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338897/python-selenium-find-out-when-a-download-has-completed

What I did to fix it is use "len([name for name in os.listdir('/tmp/downloads') if os.path.isfile(name)])" instead of scandir, which works for my purpose. By watching the tmp/downloads folder as attachments download I don't see any .crdownload files, but that would be a good idea to harden it.

The solution is to use os.listdir with the len() function. If you are using Chrome, you can also check if there is a .crdownload file.
This is an example script to wait until the /tmp/downloads directory has more than the original number of files and there isn't a .crdownload file which are placeholder files generated by Chrome. If you are not using Chrome, this script should still work.
def waitForDownload
    originalFiles = os.listdir("/tmp/downloads/")
    done = False
    while done == False:
        time.sleep(1)
        done = True
    
        files = os.listdir("/tmp/downloads")
        if len(files) == len(originalFiles)
            done = False
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith('.crdownload'):
                done = False
    return

You can use os.listdir in your code like this:
def get_attachments(driver):
    try:
        if driver.find_element(By.ID, "display-attachments-list"):
            attachments_list_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "display-attachments-list")))
            attachments_list_items = attachments_list_element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "li")
            if len(attachments_list_items) > 0:
                os.makedirs("/tmp/downloads", 511, True)
                for atch in attachments_list_items:
                    num_files = len(os.listdir("/tmp/downloads"))
                    scroll_to_element(driver, atch)
                    atch.click()
                    logger.info("Downloading attachment")
                    logger.info(atch.text)
                    for i in range(15):
                        if len(os.listdir("/tmp/downloads")) <= num_files:
                            time.sleep(1)
                        else:
                            break
                
            else:
                logger.info("No attachments found")
    except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, ElementClickInterceptedException) as e:
        logger.info("Post does not include attachments")
    scroll_to_top(driver)

