# Ruby's watchr equivalent in Python?

Tags: python, watchr

I like the concept of [watchr](https://github.com/mynyml/watchr): it monitor the file system and run a callback when something changes. Is there a pure Python equivalent? Preferably pip installable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python is related (although probably not a duplicate)

Comment: maybe pyinotify but that's only for linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably look at watchdog:

http://packages.python.org/watchdog/

Comment: Was looking for the same thing but it is more complicated to ue compared to Watchr

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, there's [watcher](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/watcher/), that is probably close to what you need although I'm not sure it provides 100% equivalent information.