# Sublime Text won't automatically change code, when I switched to different branch

Tags: eclipse, git, github, sublimetext2

Lately, I'm learning GitHub, in the tutorial videos they used Eclipse for editing the project/repository. In that vid I saw the code changed when he switch to another branch.

I'm currently using Sublime Text 2 and can't get the same behavior, is there anyway to make Sublime Text 2 behave like Eclipse?

Here is my Preferences -> Settings-User:

```
{
    "font_size": 12
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what the editor has to do with this. Are you wanting Sublime Text to detect that the file has changed on disk and update what it shows in its editor window? Or is the file not changing on disk?

Comment: Strange, this should Just Work.  Does it not update the code when you click on the editor?  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342382/file-content-in-sublime-does-not-change-on-git-branch-change

Comment: @Chris : I don't know if git / editor do that, but as I watched the tut vid the code in the editor change when I switched branch and open/click on the editor..

Comment: @jcm : No, it doesn't. I have seen that post, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should search the Sublime issue tracker or post one yourself.

Comment: This is working just fine for me using [ST3](http://sublimetext.com/3) on Win8. Can you [edit] your question with the contents of your user preferences (**`Preferences -> Settings-User`**)?