# Is there a way to restart and update running process in python like in elixir?

Tags: python, elixir, multiple-processes

I was looking for a while at elixir and control over crashing, live updating and restarting processes on the fly. Is there a lib or a way to do it in python?

Comment: You might could log breakpoints to a file, every chunk of code or so, then read that file to find out where you crashed and pick up from there. You would also want to have a memory dump on crash, likely by holding the entire deal in a try...except block, with the except block writing all the variables to the dump file.

Comment: The above is three different sets of features.  Is there something you're trying to accomplish with these options?

Am assuming you're asking this about runtime as well.

Comment: this is a feature of BEAM, I think it is not fully achievable, since things like garbage collection should be adapted for this kind of behavior. Mutability is also a big issue, since with the current reference system it is pretty much impossible to know if there are any references pointing to freed memory.

Comment: I'm trying to make update the code of current running processes without stopping whole application.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751263/hot-swapping-of-python-running-program But at this point you are just re-implementing this set of features from the BEAM.