# Lucene automatic indexer

Tags: python, lucene, indexer, pylucene

I have just started learning Lucene and would like to use it for indexing 
the hard drive and my email, what i'm wondering whether Lucene has something for 
helping me with that or I have to build some kind of observer, which watch 
for any changes int he hard drive 
as discussed in: [How do I watch a file for changes using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucene is a first and foremost a search library, implementing an inverted index and the logic around it. If you want to have automatic index updates when files on your disk change, you'll have to implement that yourself (but that - as you already researched - should not be [too difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python)).