# How to do a 'hot folder' in Python?

Tags: python

I have a directory called `input_files`. I would like a script to be triggered every time a new `xls` file is dropped into it. How would I trigger a Python script whenever this happens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try the [Watchdog](http://packages.python.org/watchdog/) library.