# Evade polling when accessing Matlab from Python

Tags: python, matlab, polling

I would like to access Matlab from Python (on Windows, remotely and via COM-interface). My goal is: Matlab is doing some work and permanently changes the value of a certain variable. I need to know when the value exceeds some constant. Right now, I'm polling Matlab for the value of that variable in an indefinite loop which breaks on exceeding the value. However, I would like to let Matlab do the work and tell *me* when that is the case, while I'm lazily sitting there listening. Is there a way to achieve this, and how is it done best? I have thought of defining a callback function I'm passing to Matlab, which on the exceed-event triggers a break out of a non-busy-wait-loop in Python, but I doubt it would work. I'm not very experienced neither in Matlab nor Python, so cues are much appreciated.

There's a lot of other code involved, but basically right now it is like

```
connectToMatlab(*args)
while True:
    val = getValueFromMatlab()
    if val > constant or timeout: break
```

What I have in mind is

```
def breakLoop():
    ...  

connectToMatlab(breakLoop, *args)
while True:
    time.sleep(1) # or some alternate non-busy-wait
```

and then let Matlab invoke `breakLoop()` upon `val > constant`. However, I don't know if it is possible to let Matlab do that with a callback and if yes, how to implement such a `breakLoop()`-Function.

Comment: Please include what code you can to show what you've tried.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not really *my* code, and I'd like to avoid trouble for posting it. I'm only supposed to find a possible solution to this and hoped for a pointer.

Comment: If you could even post a few snippets, it would help considerably. Like the call to python, etc. Very rarely are snippets a problem. Plus, if you could create your own independed simple code base, it helps even further, and I've answered more than one of my own questions in the process of writing such a code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go about this the other way, and use the file system as a way to pass the messages between MATLAB and Python.

Inside your MATLAB code, each time you change the variable, check if it exceed some threshold. If it does, create a new file in a predetermined location. Think of this as triggering an event.

Now inside your python code, use some of the available ways to the [listen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python) to [changes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/156178-watching-a-directory-under-win32/) in the file system, and respond by indicating some variable to break the loop.

---

### EDIT

Here is a skeleton of the solution proposed:

#### matlab_script.m

```
%# directory that Python code is watching for modifications
dirPath = 'some_directory';

x = 0;
for i=1:1000
    %# some lengthy operation
    pause(0.5)
    x = x + 1;

    %# check if variable exceeds threshold
    if x > 10
        %# save the workspace to MAT-file inside the directory watched.
        %# this shall trigger the notification in Python
        save( fullfile(dirPath,'out.mat') )
        break
    end
end
```

#### python_code.py

```
import os, sys, time
import win32file, win32event, win32con

# stub your functions in my case
def connectToMatlab():
  pass
def getValueFromMatlab():
  return 99

# path to predetermined directory to watch
dirPath = "some_directory"
dirPath = os.path.abspath(dirPath)

# start/connect to a MATLAB session, running the script above
connectToMatlab()

# set up folder watching (notify on file addition/deletion/renaming)
print "Started watching '%s' at %s" % (dirPath, time.asctime())
change_handle = win32file.FindFirstChangeNotification(
  dirPath, 0, win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME)

# time-out in 10 sec (win32event.INFINITE to wait indefinitely)
timeout = 10000

try:
  # block/wait for notification
  result = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(change_handle, timeout)

  # returned because of a change notification
  if result == win32con.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
    # retrieve final result from MATLAB
    print "MALTAB variable has exceeded threshold at %s" % time.asctime()
    val = getValueFromMatlab()

  # timed out
  elif result == win32con.WAIT_TIMEOUT:
    print "timed-out after %s msec at %s" % (timeout,time.asctime())
    val = None    # maybe to indicate failure

finally:
  # cleanup properly
  win32file.FindCloseChangeNotification(change_handle)

# work with val
print val
```

The [`WaitForSingleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx) function start by checking the state of the specified object. If it is nonsignaled, the calling thread enters an efficient wait state and consumes very little processor time while waiting until the object is signaled (or the time-out interval elapses).

You see when the thread references the object which is in non-signaled state, there is an immediate context switch i.e. it is taken down from the processor and put into a wait/sleep mode. Later when the object is signaled, the thread is put back to the runnable queue and is ready for execution.

In this kind of waiting there is no wastage of CPU cycles in wait state, although there is a some overhead in context switching.

Compare this against the "poll-and-wait" approach, where the thread waits and checks for the state of the object of interest in some kind of a loop. This is known as spin or busy wait, which can prove to be a wastage of CPU cycles.

Now thanks to pywin32 module, we can use use those [`WaitFor...`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069.aspx) functions directly. The implementation should be a straightforward port of the [standard example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261.aspx) given in MSDN.

Alternatively you can use the PyQt library with its [QFileSystemWatcher](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qfilesystemwatcher.html) class instead of directly using the Win32 API.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a hint on msdn whether `WaitForSingleObject` does a kind of busy wait itself or not. Anyway +1 for the "treat file as messenger"-idea.

Comment: @AFriedrich: actually the `WaitFor*` functions are very efficient, see my explanation above.. I also posted an example implementation

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll try this approach and leave a notice when I got it into working code (though may take a while).