# How to check in python that a file in a folder has changed?

Tags: python, inotify

I need to know in python whenever a new file was added/removed/modified in a particular directory 
Is there a way for that? 
I'm looking for an "inofity"-like function (from POSIX).

Thanks

Comment: *python inotify* -> **pyinotify** https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki

Comment: I had an answer to this, but it kept being downvoted, no matter it's been 7 years ago. So, whatever, I deleted it.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [inotify for python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inotify), which is **NOT** the same as *PyInotify* (older).

Comment: Their examples don't work: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inotify.adapters'; 'inotify' is not a package

Comment: Have you installed the module?

Comment: Did you call the script inotify.py? This will break importing a package called inotify.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/182197/321973), you might want to have a look at http://packages.python.org/watchdog/ which also works on Windows.