# Detecting file opening in Linux

Tags: python, linux, file

I'm writing a daemon, monitoring user activity on Linux. Is there any way to detect opening arbitrary file by arbitrary process? Preferred language is Python/C/C++

Comment: You could use [`inotify(7)`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify).

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023608/check-what-files-are-open-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check in python that a file in a folder has changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582720/how-to-check-in-python-that-a-file-in-a-folder-has-changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux has group of [`inotify` system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).

There is a Python wrapper for these called [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify).