# How do i track the process of transferringt data from any external usb to PC (linux) ?

Tags: python, linux, unix, operating-system

I want to write a python script which will keep track while transferring data from external USB to hard disk , I want to track the location of the data being transferred and the time at which the Process ends .(Through CLI) .

I have searched many places on internet but found nothing relevant. Any idea how can I start?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check in python that a file in a folder has changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582720/how-to-check-in-python-that-a-file-in-a-folder-has-changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a piece in the kernel that can monitor accesses to the filesystem and "[notify](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify)" other processes whenever it happens

It is exported to c libraries, it is exported to [python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inotify) (and even bash!).

You can then find the other files that process access using:

```
lsof -p <PID>
```