# Python registering to Windows file-system modifications

Tags: python, windows, io, filesystems, listener

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I watch a file for changes using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python)

How can a long-running python script register to Windows so as to be notified of modifications (files and folders creation/modification/deletion) in a file-system subtree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [watchdog](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog), it is hiring ReadDirectoryChangesW underley for Windows