# How to do notifications with Python 3.3?

Tags: python-3.x, notifications, watchdog

I'm working on a python app that needs a notification when there's a change in a directory structure; e.g., someone drops a file in a folder or changes a file name. Reading up on Watchdog, it looks like it does just what I need except that I'm working in Python 3.3 and Watchdog doesn't seem to have been updated. Below is the tail end of an error dump from a watchdog sample file.

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python33\lib\site-packages\watchdog-0.6.0-py3.3.egg\watchdog\utils\bricks.py", line 112, in <module>
  if not sys.version < (2, 6, 0):
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < tuple()
```

I just tried installing Pyinotify but got an error saying it's not available with Win64. How does one go about receiving notifications with Python 3.3 and Win64?

Comment: Have you tried methods from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python

Answer (score 1):

[`sys.version`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/sys#sys.version) is a `str`. You should use tuple and [`sys.version_info`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/sys#sys.version_info) is what you need.