# Write a file hook in python to move the latest location of the file

Tags: pyqt5

I want to be able to drag and drop files remotely in python.

Since I can't get the destination path after the drag and drop, I'm considering using the file hook to get the location of the temporary file I created after the move.

But I don't know how to implement file hooks in python.

I found a case of a file hook written in c++. Can anyone take the time to translate it into python?
https://github.com/Eyre-Turing/file_hook.

mark:
I have tried to use watchdog to monitor the moving directory, but I am sorry that watchdog cannot do it.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "drag and drop files remotely"? Drag from what? And to what? Please be more clear.

Comment: If you want to trigger some script or have a folder monitored so that a script can perform the actions then you can use "watchdog" its a python library which does exactly same.  Here is a link to the thread have a look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599339/watchdog-monitoring-file-for-changes

Comment: I want to implement drag and drop download server files to the local. Since files take a long time to download, I need to know the destination path for the drag and drop. I tried to use watchdog to listen to the target path where the file was moved, but watchdog could not listen for movement events.