# hook file creation in python

Tags: python, hook, pydbg, event-hooking

I'm working on a program, where in some part of it, it needs to listen to the OP for when files are created/saved, so I can work on said file.
I know the basic concept of hooking, but I don't know exactly how to implement it in this specific use(I know how to attach a hook to a specific PID, but here I need to listen to all processes and see if one of them is creating a file).
I'm using pydbg for my hooking needs, but if your answer uses something different, feel free to still answer.
Thanks :)

Comment: programmers.stackexchange.com might be a better forum. They allow design questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need something like [watchdog](http://packages.python.org/watchdog/), [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify) or [python-inotify](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-inotify). You can also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python) for other options.

Comment: Thanks :)
The question you referred me to had the answer I was looking for!
Helped a lot