# How to get a file close event in python

Tags: python, windows, file, process, file-monitoring

Using python 2.7 on windows 7 64 bit machine.

How to get a file close event:

1. when file is opened in a new process of file opener (like notepad, wordpad which opens file everytime in new process of wordpad)
2. when file is opened in a tab of file opener (like notepad++, which opens all files in new tab but there exist only a single process of notepad++ running)

So, how to get file close event in above cases? Is it possible to achieve above cases through  a common code? I am dealing with different file types

Answer (score 19):

This has proven to be a very easy task for *nix systems, but on Windows, getting a file close event is not a simple task. Read below the summary of common methods grouped by OS'es.

## For Linux

On Linux, the filesystem changes can be easily monitored, and in great detail. The best tool for this is the kernel feature called `inotify`, and there is a Python implementation that uses it, called Pynotify.

- ### [Pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify)

  `Pyinotify` is a Python module for monitoring filesystems changes. Pyinotify relies on a Linux Kernel feature (merged in kernel 2.6.13) called `inotify`, which is an event-driven notifier. Its notifications are exported from kernel space to user space through three system calls. `Pyinotify` binds these system calls and provides an implementation on top of them offering a generic and abstract way to manipulate those functionalities.

  [Here](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/#The_EventsCodes_Class) you can find the list of the events that can be monitored with `Pynotify`.

  **Example usage:**

  import pyinotify

  ```
  class EventHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
      def process_IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE(self, event):
          print "File was closed without writing: " + event.pathname
      def process_IN_CLOSE_WRITE(self, event):
          print "File was closed with writing: " + event.pathname

  def watch(filename):
      wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
      mask = pyinotify.IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE | pyinotify.IN_CLOSE_WRITE
      wm.add_watch(filename, mask)

      eh = EventHandler()
      notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, eh)
      notifier.loop()

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      watch('/path/to/file')
  ```

## For Windows

Situation for Windows is quite a bit more complex than for Linux. Most libraries rely on `ReadDirectoryChanges` API which is restricted and can't detect finer details like file close event. There are however other methods for detecting such events, so read on to find out more.

- ### [Watcher](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watcher)

  **Note:** Watcher has been last updated in February 2011, so its probably safe to skip this one.

  `Watcher` is a low-level `C` extension for receiving file system updates using the `ReadDirectoryChangesW` API on Windows systems. The package also includes a high-level interface to emulate most of the .NET `FileSystemWatcher` API.
  The closest one can get to detecting file close events with Watcher is to monitor the `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE` and/or `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_ACCESS` events.

  **Example usage:**

  ```
  import watcher
  w = watcher.Watcher(dir, callback)
  w.flags = watcher.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE
  w.start()
  ```
- ### [Watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog/0.5.4)

  Python API and shell utilities to monitor file system events. Easy install: `$ pip install watchdog`. For more info visit the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/).
  Watchdog on Windows relies on the `ReadDirectoryChangesW` API, which brings its caveats as with Watcher and other libraries relying on the same API.
- ### [Pywatch](https://github.com/cmheisel/pywatch)

  A python near-clone of the Linux `watch` command. The `pywatch.watcher.Watcher` class can be told to watch a set of files, and given a set of commands to run whenever any of those files change. It can only monitor the file changed event, since it relies on polling the [stat's st_mtime](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).

#### Bonus for Windows with NTFS:

- ### [NTFS USN Journal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USN_Journal)

  The NTFS USN (Update Sequence Number) Journal is a feature of NTFS which maintains a record of changes made to the volume. The reason it is listed as a *Bonus* is because unlike the other entries, it is not a specific library, but rather a feature existing on NTFS system. So if you are using other Windows filesystems (like FAT, ReFS, etc..) this does not apply.
  The way it works it that the system records all changes made to the volume in the USN Journal file, with each volume having its own instance. Each record in the Change Journal contains the USN, the name of the file, and information about what the change was.

  The main reason this method is interesting for this question is that, unlike most of the other methods, this one provides a way to detect a **file close** event, defined as **USN_REASON_CLOSE**. More information with a complete list of events can be found in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365722(v=vs.85).aspx). For a complete documentation about USN Journaling, visit this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363798%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

  There are multiple ways to access the USN Journal from Python, but the only mature option seems to be the **[ntfsjournal](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ntfsjournal)** module.

#### The "proper" way for Windows:

- ### [File system filter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

  As descibed on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557282(v=vs.85).aspx):

  > A file system filter driver is an optional driver that adds value to
  >   or modifies the behavior of a file system. A file system filter driver
  >   is a kernel-mode component that runs as part of the Windows executive.
  >   A file system filter driver can filter I/O operations for one or more
  >   file systems or file system volumes. Depending on the nature of the
  >   driver, filter can mean log, observe, modify, or even prevent. Typical
  >   applications for file system filter drivers include antivirus
  >   utilities, encryption programs, and hierarchical storage management
  >   systems.

  It is not an easy task to implement a file system filter driver, but for someone who would like to give it a try, there is a good introduction tutorial on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43586/File-System-Filter-Driver-Tutorial).

  P.S. Check  [@ixe013's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22646476/2842884) for some additional info about this method.

## Multiplatform

- ### [Qt's QFileSystemWatcher](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemwatcher.html)

  The `QFileSystemWatcher` class provides an interface for monitoring files and directories for modifications. This class was introduced in `Qt 4.2`.
  Unfortunately, its functionality is fairly limited, as it can only detect when a file has been modified, renamed or deleted, and when a new file was added to a directory.

  **Example usage:**

  ```
  import sys
  from PyQt4 import QtCore

  def directory_changed(path):
      print('Directory Changed: %s' % path)

  def file_changed(path):
      print('File Changed: %s' % path)

  app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

  paths = ['/path/to/file']
  fs_watcher = QtCore.QFileSystemWatcher(paths)
  fs_watcher.directoryChanged.connect(directory_changed)
  fs_watcher.fileChanged.connect(file_changed)

  app.exec_()
  ```

Comment: these pynotify and inotify are for linux. I want for windows. We cant install these libraries on windows

Comment: all the above libraries and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python are for monitoring file changes. But I do not find any event to monitor file close.

Comment: Ofcourse there are such events. Pynotify for example implements the close_write, close_nowrite and close events, which do exactly what you want. On Windows, Watcher implements IN_CLOSE_WRITE and IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE to detect such events.

Comment: can you please elaborate Watcher, or its documentation link

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have access to windows at this time, or I would try it myself. The documentation is quite short, but it shows that you should create an watcher.Watcher object and set its `flags` property to a desired event.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. I am also trying hard to solve this issue

Comment: I am not able to find watcher.IN_CLOSE_WRITE or watcher.IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE event. Please let me know the code,you are using

Comment: Sorry, I am not using watcher, I use inotify on Linux. It could be that not all events are covered with all libraries. I just checked again, and it seems i was looking at the Watcher version for Linux: https://github.com/gregghz/Watcher - you can see there the IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE event. Not sure how this is implemented in Windows.

Comment: thanks for your concern. But I am not able to apply this with python.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are facing is not with Python, but with Windows. It can be done, but you will have to write some non-trival C/C++ code for it.

A file open or a file close user mode notification does not exist in userland on Windows. That's why the libraries suggested by others do not have file close notification. In Windows, the API to detect changes in userland is [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It will alert you of [one of the following notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

- `FILE_ACTION_ADDED` if a file was added to the directory.
- `FILE_ACTION_REMOVED` if a file was removed from the directory.
- `FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED` if a file was modified. This can be a change in the time stamp or attributes.
- `FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_OLD_NAME` if a file was renamed and this is the old name.
- `FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_NEW_NAME` if a file was renamed and this is the new name.

No amount of Python can change what Windows provides you with.

To get a file close notification, [tools like Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) install a [Minifilter that lives in the kernel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), near the top of other filters like EFS.

To acheive what you want, you would need to:

1. Install a Minifilter that has the code to send events back to userland. Use [Microsoft's Minispy sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Minispy-File-System-97844844), it is stable and fast.
2. Convert the code from the `user` program to make it a Python extension (`minispy.pyd`) that exposes a generator that produces the events. This is the hard part, I will get back to that.
3. You will have to filter out events, you won't beleive the amount of IO goes on an idle Windows box!
4. Your Python program can then import your extension and do its thing.

The whole thing looks something like this :

[image: A Python wrapper over a Windows Minifilter for filesystem events]

Of course you can have EFS over NTFS, this is just to show that your minifilter would be above all that.

The hard parts :

- Your minifilter will have to be digitally signed by an authority Microsoft trusts. Verising comes to mind but there are others.
- Debugging requires a separate (virtual) machine, but you can make your interface easy to mock.
- You will need to install the minifilter with an account that has adminstrator rights. Any user will be able to read events.
- You will have to deal with multi-users your self. There is only one minifilter for many users.
- You will have to convert user program from the MiniSpy sample to a DLL, which you will wrap with a Python extension.

The last two are the hardest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pyfanotyfi](https://bitbucket.org/mjs0/pyfanotify) or [butter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/butter/0.3).

I think you'll find this link very usefull: [Linux file system events with C, Python and Ruby](http://markusjais.com/linux-file-system-events-with-c-python-and-ruby/)

There you will find an example about doing exactly what you want(using [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki)) this is the code:

```
import pyinotify

DIR_TO_WATCH="/tmp/notify-dir"
FILE_TO_WATCH="/tmp/notify-dir/notify-file.txt"

wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()

dir_events = pyinotify.IN_DELETE | pyinotify.IN_CREATE
file_events = pyinotify.IN_OPEN | pyinotify.IN_CLOSE_WRITE | pyinotify.IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE

class EventHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    def process_IN_DELETE(self, event):
        print("File %s was deleted" % event.pathname) #python 3 style print function
    def process_IN_CREATE(self, event):
        print("File %s was created" % event.pathname)
    def process_IN_OPEN(self, event):
        print("File %s was opened" % event.pathname)
    def process_IN_CLOSE_WRITE(self, event):
        print("File %s was closed after writing" % event.pathname)
    def process_IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE(self, event):
        print("File %s was closed after reading" % event.pathname)

event_handler = EventHandler()
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, event_handler)

wm.add_watch(DIR_TO_WATCH, dir_events)
wm.add_watch(FILE_TO_WATCH, file_events)

notifier.loop()
```

Comment: pyinotify is for linux. I want for Windows. We cant install pyinotify on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a package that captures `open` and `close` events on Windows. As others have mentioned, [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify), is an excellent option for Linux based operating systems.

Since I wasn't able to watch for the closed event, I settled for the modified event. It's very much an 'after the fact' type of solution (ie. I can't pause until I see a file is closed). But, this has worked surprisingly well.

I've used the [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog/0.5.4) package. The code below is from their [sample](http://pythonhosted.org//watchdog/quickstart.html#a-simple-example) implementation and watches the current directory if you don't pass a path on the command line, otherwise it watches the path you pass.

Example call:  `python test.py` or `python test.py C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop`

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

This code will show you when files are created, modified, deleted or renamed/moved. You can filter by just modified by watching for the `on_modified` [event](http://pythonhosted.org//watchdog/api.html#module-watchdog.events).

Comment: I am able to catch the modified event by `os.path.getmtime(filename)`.Actually I want to delete the file as soon as it is closed(both either file is close from a tab of notepad++ or normal notepad). User can modify a file many times before closing a file.

Comment: @imp I think all answers here are wrong because they try to answer the question on a close event on file system level whereas your comment suggests you want the close event on application level‽  Closing a file on file system level is something different than closing a document in an application unless the application really opens the file at the beginning and closes it at the end.  Which is quite unlikely in the case of text editors. When opening a document they open the file, read the content, and close it. Closing the document in the editor then generates _no_ event on file system level!