# How to catch file close event in python

Tags: python, process, watchdog, file-monitoring, qfilesystemwatcher

Using python 2.7 on windows 7 64 bit machine.
How to get a file close event:

1. when file is opened in a new process of file opener (like notepad,
   wordpad which opens file everytime in new process of wordpad)
2. when file is opened in a tab of file opener (like notepad++, which
   opens all files in new tab but there exist only a single process of
   notepad++ running)

So, how to get file close event in above cases? Is it possible to achieve above cases through a common code? I am dealing with different file types.

It can also be solved by this scheme, *when a file opens, a certain process handles it. And when it closes, all processes which controls it are also lost*. 
So, we can know whether a file is closed or not.

I posted this in [this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406309/how-to-get-a-file-close-event-in-python?noredirect=1#comment34068554_22406309),  and tried with watchdog, pywatch and Watcher but not able to get file close event

Comment: So you don't mean catching as in exceptions, but rather detecting a file system event?

Comment: This question contains some more discussion on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114492/check-if-a-file-is-not-open-not-used-by-other-process-in-python

Comment: @2rs2ts file system event is just a way to achieve file close event. I want basically file close event