# Event listening and handling in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, events, listener

I will start out by saying I have never done events and triggers in anything other than javascript.

I have a thread that runs and processes all the files in a folder. I want this thread to run everytime a new file writes to that folder. I thought events would be the way to do that, but I have no idea how to do that in python.

How do you tell a thread to throw or trigger an event? How does another thread pick this up?

sample thread:

```
def list_files_thread(dir):
    for filename in os.listdir(dir):
        print filename

thread.start_new_thread(list_files_thread, ('output',))
```

Edit: 
I am new to mutlithreading, so maybe I should use this instead?

```
class list_files_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, directory):
        self.directory = directory
    def run(self):
        list_files(self.directory)

def list_files(directory_path):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
        print filename
```

Comment: not the answer to your question, but you should really use `threading` and not `thread`.  The former is the high-level API, the latter is rather low-level.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'm new to multithreading as well...

Comment: I think you might be better suited with multiprocessing than threading. Take a look at multiprocessing.Queue

Comment: What you want is that your code be able to detect when a new file is created in that folder. Is that correct?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda I am trying to make a platform independent program, but I am currently on Windows. Yes, the idea is that this thread would list the files in the dir (or whatever action), maybe move them to a "processed" folder, and anytime a new file is written, it would rerun the thread.

Comment: @FlorianLudwig that's not really sound advice.  Threading is ideal for i/o operations.  `multiprocessing` introduces a lot of complications like interprocess transfer of non-picklable information that you just don't have to deal with when using threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the typical way to trigger asynchronous events is to use the [`signal`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) module. As the documentation notes, signals *cannot* be used for inter-thread communication, so threads would be inappropriate in this case. Of course, you can also use threads using [`threading.Condition`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Condition) objects.

That being said, asynchronous events, threads, and signals are confusing and hard to implement correctly. Are you sure you want to reinvent the wheel? (You very well might be; I just like to check.) If not, [`watchdog`](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/) provides the exact capabilities you require.

Comment: Couldn't I just create a watchdog thread that monitors. In that thread, if it detects a change, it spawns a "list_dir" thread?

Comment: Sure - there's many, many ways to accomplish the same thing (although there is usually one preferred way in python). I'm not sure of your desired end goal, and I'm not sure what a list_dir thread would do. You asked about events specifically, so beyond that, you should really post a separate question.

Comment: Does my answer implement what you were talking about?

Comment: Well, the best way is to find out is to just go ahead and test it! (However, I also won't just leave you hanging - yes, it seems to do what you originally set out to accomplish from the brief description you provided.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not a problem of `python events` it's more about *Operative System Signals*. You will need some way of monitoring the changes in the target folder. Since you are planning  your code to be multiplatform I recommend you work with Qt specifically `QtCore.QFileSystemWatcher`.

Here are you have an aswer that can help you: [How do I watch a file for changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python)

Comment: Thanks! If I have access to the script that would write files to that folder, would this be a different situation?

Comment: Well, of course. Then you only need to implement and `obserber pattern` and combine it with a `Provider consumer pattern` I'll update the answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the great answers.

This is the code I ended up using:

```
def list_files(directory_path):
    print directory_path
    parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(directory_path, os.pardir))
    print parent_dir
    for filename in os.listdir(parent_dir):
         print filename

class trigger_event_handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        super(trigger_event_handler, self).on_created(event)
        list_files(event.src_path)


new_event_handler = trigger_event_handler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(new_event_handler, output_dir, recursive=False)
observer.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```