# How do I watch a file, not a directory for changes using Python?

Tags: python, file, watch, python-watchdog

The question: [How do I watch a file for changes using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python) suggests using watchdog, but I found it was only able to watch a directory, not a file. [watchdog-test.py](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog#example-api-usage) is watchdog's sample script:

```
$ python watchdog-test.py ab_test_res.sh &
[1] 30628
fbt@fbt64:~/laike9m$ Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "watchdog-test.py", line 15, in <module>
    observer.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/watchdog/observers/api.py", line 255, in start
    emitter.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/watchdog/utils/__init__.py", line 111, in start
    self.on_thread_start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/watchdog/observers/inotify.py", line 121, in on_thread_start
    self._inotify = InotifyBuffer(path, self.watch.is_recursive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/watchdog/observers/inotify_buffer.py", line 35, in __init__
    self._inotify = Inotify(path, recursive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/watchdog/observers/inotify_c.py", line 187, in __init__
    self._add_dir_watch(path, recursive, event_mask)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/watchdog/observers/inotify_c.py", line 363, in _add_dir_watch
    raise OSError('Path is not a directory')
OSError: Path is not a directory
```

So what's the best solution? I'm using Linux(Ubuntu 12.04). BTW I don't want to use polling.

Comment: What operating system? I don't know for sure, but I think Windows only supports watching directories.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Linux.

Comment: look into inotify http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify

Comment: I was able to do same what you ask in perl. I try to seek file continuously for any changes but put a sleep between every seek. This will help to keep load on system less. If you want my perl solution i can provide it to you.

Comment: @shivams That's polling isn't it, but I'm looking for another way.

Comment: @laike9m yeah i know that is polling but any module you use will have to do the same(i think so). In my case load was less  and performance was good. So i thought about giving my view here.

Comment: @laike9m Ok i do little search on internet and i am wrong. Every module will not do polling. You can try using notify in python which look like a solution to your problem.

Comment: @shivams I'll try pyinotify.

Comment: @laike9m If you find a working solution to your problem do post it here so that others will be able to learn from that.

Comment: @shivams Sure I will.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can watch a file with watchdog by watching the directory that the file is in and only responding to change events that effect your file.  Something like this would do it for you:

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class FileModifiedHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def __init__(self, path, file_name, callback):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.callback = callback

        # set observer to watch for changes in the directory
        self.observer = Observer()
        self.observer.schedule(self, path, recursive=False)
        self.observer.start()
        self.observer.join()

    def on_modified(self, event): 
        # only act on the change that we're looking for
        if not event.is_directory and event.src_path.endswith(self.file_name):
            self.observer.stop() # stop watching
            self.callback() # call callback


from sys import argv, exit

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if not len(argv) == 2:
        print("No file specified")
        exit(1)

    def callback():
        print("FILE WAS MODIFED")

    FileModifiedHandler('.', argv[1], callback)
```

I was only able to test this on windows, but it should be os agnostic.