# Is there a method in Python to "check" if a textfile has been modified or appended?

Tags: python-3.x, file

I am trying to create a python script that will keep track of a log file which is piped output from a console. If an "Error" pops up in it, I would like to send myself a telegram message (I know that API) so I can get a notification that I got an error. So what I would like to do is simply this in pseudocode

```
while true:
    if isModified(file):
         print(changed_text)
```

I'm not sure if something like this is possible, but it would be great if someone can assist with an idea or process.

Comment: So basically, you want to listen/watch for changes to a file?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Yes! Hopefully in Python, as I'm most comfortable with it.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30531477/8200485) may help you