# Determine if a file is done being written from windows to linux

Tags: python

I have python process (running on linux) was listen to directory.

Another process (running on Windows), write files to the same directory which the linux python process listen to.

I want to handle file only when if the file done being written to.

I'm trying to suggesting from [Need a way to determine if a file is done being written to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070210/need-a-way-to-determine-if-a-file-is-done-being-written-to).

Trying also to open the file with `w` mode, Trying to check the date modified of the file periodically but in linux it's changed only when the file is finish to write (and I don't know like that if the file still writting or it's done).

All of that I have been tried is failed and i'm not able to know if the the windows process finish to write the file into the directory.

NOTE: I don't have the source code of the windows process - blackbox.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Use a lockfile with a library like https://pypi.org/project/fasteners/ .

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531477/how-do-i-watch-a-file-not-a-directory-for-changes-using-python

Comment: I dont have the source code of the windows process

Comment: You’re basically out of luck: there is *no way* to make this work with your constraints. You’ll need a workaround, such as creating a second process on Windows which tests if the first process terminated, and which communicates with your Linux process.

Comment: @KonradRudolph which another alternatives I have?

Comment: @MarTeen I can’t think of any that are practical. Having a monitoring process running on the Windows machine is definitely the easiest, and might be the only one that’s feasible at all.

Comment: @KonradRudolph what about check ```os.path.getmtime``` it's could help?

Comment: That doesn’t help.

Comment: @KonradRudolph why not?

Comment: What do you mean? It doesn't work because it doesn't do anything useful in this context. How do you think it would help you?