# Can I get the modified time of the registry value on the window?

Tags: python, windows, registry

Can I get the modified time of the registry value on the window? If yes how can I get the above value. Can I get it in python? Example I need to get the modified time of value name: "update_url" as shown below:

[image]

Comment: @funie200, that thread doesn't point how to get the modification time of a key

Comment: This thread might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34738466/1374644

Comment: Thanks, It means I can't get the time modified of the value but can only get the time modified of the key?