# How to get notification on ubuntu when changes in windows machine directory?

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-2.7

I have two machines:

(Both machines are in same network)

1. `Linux` machine (`ubuntu 16.04`), and
2. `Windows` machine (`Win 7`)

I need to create a watch on directory of windows machine and  when any file or directory created (required for recursive directories) then the notification sends to the Linux machine that what changes are done.

I have tried with the python library:

https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools

But it having bug that it's not working for the recursive directory and might not support in windows.

Comment: so your question can *either* be [tag:python-2.7] *or* [tag:python-3.4], not both. If you don't care, remove both tags.

Comment: I need solution for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem and solved it by just polling for files and directories with a modification date set after the last poll.

Comment: Hi @Jacques de Hooge, will u please provide some link or small demo to do this, I am not getting how to do polling for files.

Comment: you list all files and directories. You check whether they are the same as last time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python See answer by Deestan.. But: Poll in a thread and add a sleep of e.g. 5 sec to avoid polling to much. Traverse dir tree by using    os.walk () and poll file by file.

Comment: Its not working for me ! :(

Comment: We have synology rack server is it matter, because windows is in rack server.