# wait until dynamically-updating csv has X number of rows before executing (python 2.7)

Tags: python, csv, timer, scheduler

I would like to check a csv file (either continuously, or every x seconds/milliseconds), and execute a function after the csv has reached a critical number of rows.

I've seen apscheduler, but am thinking there is a simpler way to do this.

Your help is much appreciated!

Python 2.7, Unix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I watch a file for changes using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `asyncio` module to achieve that, with Python 3.5, a working example can be as follows:

```
import asyncio

required_lines = 3
sleep_seconds = 2


async def count_lines(loop):
    num_lines = open('file_name.csv').read().count('\n')
    while num_lines != required_lines:
        await asyncio.sleep(sleep_seconds)
        num_lines = open('file_name.csv').read().count('\n')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(count_lines(loop))
loop.close()
```

With Python 3.4, use the following `count_lines` function instead of the above one:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def count_lines(loop):
    num_lines = open('file_name.csv').read().count('\n')
    while num_lines != required_lines:
        yield from asyncio.sleep(sleep_seconds)
        num_lines = open('file_name.csv').read().count('\n')
```

**Edit:** for Python 2.7 you can use `trollius` library as shown below (`trollius` still works but it is no longer maintained!):

```
import trollius
from trollius import From


required_lines = 3
sleep_seconds = 2

@trollius.coroutine
def count_lines():
    num_lines = open('file_name.txt').read().count('\n')
    while num_lines != required_lines:
        yield From(trollius.sleep(sleep_seconds))
        num_lines = open('file_name.txt').read().count('\n')

loop = trollius.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(count_lines())
```

Comment: thanks! I just realized that the environment everything we run on is in python 2.7.... :/

Comment: In this case you can use `trollius` which is an asyncio-like library for Python 2.7

Comment: based on import error and a quick search, I think trollius is deprecated :(

Comment: Take a look at the example that I added above. Yes `trollius` is deprecated but I tested it and it still works. If you can create a virtual environment with Python 3.x that would be better.

Comment: oops, just needed a pip install. thank you very much!! :)