# How does django detect file changes

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to watch for changes in .py files, in a directory.
I went through [existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python).
I'm curious on how django library solves this problem. The development server is restarted on file changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code can be found in [`django.utils.autoreload`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/autoreload.py). The autoreloader uses a separate thread that watches any python module that has been imported, and any translation file.

If [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) is available, Django uses that to listen to change events. Otherwise, it checks the timestamps of every file every second. If there are any changes, the process is restarted.

Django's autoreloader [may not be the best source of inspiration](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-developers/voXNIDdDcpU/mnmr9NCPCgAJ). Better options may be [Watchman](https://github.com/facebook/watchman) (with the appropriate python bindings) or the pure-python alternative [Watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog).

Comment: This answer's solution was removed in Django 2.2. @hard's answer is current.

Answer (score 5):

Fast forward to April 2019:

With [django 2.2](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27685#comment:18) [pywatchman](https://pypi.org/project/pywatchman/) as part of [Watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/) will be supported and pyinotify (being [unmaintained since mid 2015](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/issues/1500#issuecomment-386799612)) is dropped:

> If you're using Linux or MacOS and install both `pywatchman` and the
>   `Watchman` service, kernel signals will be used to autoreload the server
>   (rather than polling file modification timestamps each second). This offers
>   better performance on large projects, reduced response time after code changes,
>   more robust change detection, and a reduction in power usage.

source: [django-admin](https://github.com/django/django/commit/c8720e7696ca41f3262d5369365cc1bd72a216ca#diff-b5ea25a58e9c8adf1a328182844020ca)

> When using Watchman with a project that includes large non-Python
>       directories like `node_modules`, it's advisable to ignore this directory
>       for optimal performance.

See the [`watchman documentation`](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/config.html#ignore_dirs) for information on how to do this.