# Automatically overwrite existing file with an incoming file

Tags: python, bash, bluetooth, rename, overwrite

as of right now I have a file called song.mp3 that I have integrated into a Python program which will act as an alarm. I would like it so that whenever I send the Raspberry Pi a new song via Bluetooth, it will just automatically rename this song to be song.mp3, thereby overwriting the previous song. That way I don't have to change my alarm program for different songs. Any help?

Comment: Or maybe is there a way to constantly check a directory for new files, and then automatically rename those new files? Thanks

Comment: There's a technique called _Poll the directory with os.listdir_ in Tim Golden's Python Stuff article [_Watch a Directory for Changes_](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html) that might be good enough. I've also heard of some Linux-only modules that do this sort of thing, but I don't recall their names. Also see [**_How do I watch a file for changes?_**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the mp3 files are all in the same directory, you could perhaps have a cron job running that periodically renames the most recent file and so something like:

mv $(ls -1t *.txt | head -1) song.mp3

This is a quick example. It would be more preferable to add the ablve to a script and add some "belts and braces" to ensure that the script doesn't crash.