# How can I monitor file changes in a pyqt qlistview?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I open a file in a Qlistview, If the file changes, maybe a  line removed or a line changes, I'd like it to show on the qlistview as well. How can I do this?

My qlistview is pretty standard as defined below. Basically what I'm asking for is a way to automatically refresh the qlistview while changes are detected somehow...

```
with open(filex, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        self.item = QtGui.QStandardItem(line)
        self.item.setCheckable(True)
        self.item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        self.model.appendRow(self.item)
    self.list_view.setModel(self.model)
```

Answer (score 0):

Qt has a `QFileSystemWatcher` class that can monitor if a file has changed. Simply register your file with the `addPath` method and connect the `fileChanged` signal to a slot that updates your list model.

Be aware that monitoring files can consume resources, so be sure to read the notes about this in the [detailed description of the QFileSystemWatcher](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html#details).

BTW: in case the `QFileSystemWatcher` doesn't work out, there is also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes) on how to monitor file changes in Python in general.