# Python Program that monitors a file and retrieves the new appended content

Tags: python, inotify

May I ask that how to start writing a py that can monitor a file and, when this file is open and appends with new content, then py shall retrieve the new content in the program?

Is it possible to use `pynotify` to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I watch a file for changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes)

Comment: let's say we are working on linux...

Comment: Yeah I figure this out. Strongly recommend `watchdog`.