# Triggering a python script using a trigger

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a simple python script trigger based. I have a .py file save in a folder on my windows machine and I am looking to run the script everytime a .txt file in the same is refreshed. Is it something I can do in python.
Would really appreciate any help here.

Thank You

Comment: You may find useful tools by doing a web search for "filesystem event monitoring python".

Comment: You could improve your question by increasing question clarity a little bit more details and showing your current progress (what research you've performed, any code you've written). There is a [guide how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also I am pretty sure that your question is a duplicate. Another simmilar question was asked [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I watch a file for changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes)